# upload file to asp.net website

Tags: html, file-upload, input

i have the below html code in order to upload maximum 3 files to my database. only the first button opens the dialog and get the path string to  filename3  input text. how can i fix it for all 3 upload text inputs?

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="upload.." name="btn1 " id="btn1" class="file_input_button" style="width: 20%; height: 16%; position: absolute; top: 25%; right: 10%;" />
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" class="file_input_hidden" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName1').value = this.value" />
    <input type="text" name="fileName1" id="fileName1" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly" style="width: 55%; height: 10%; position: absolute; top: 25%; right: 32%;" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="upload.." name="btn2 " id="btn2" class="file_input_button" style="width: 20%; height: 16%; position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 10%;" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" class="file_input_hidden" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName2').value = this.value" />
    <input type="text" name="fileName2" id="fileName2" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly" style="width: 55%; height: 10%; position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 32%;" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="upload.." name="btn3 " id="btn3" class="file_input_button" style="width: 20%; height: 16%; position: absolute; top: 75%; right: 10%;" />
    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" class="file_input_hidden" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName3').value = this.value" />
    <input type="text" name="fileName3" id="fileName3" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly" style="width: 55%; height: 10%; position: absolute; top: 75%; right: 32%;" />
</div>
```

Comment: please explain a bit more.

Comment: i have 3 buttons with 3 text input for selected path (one button to one input). only the first button "btn1" open the file dialog window and after i choose a file i get the path in the input text "file3" that relate to "btn3".all other buttons dont work.

Comment: You tagged this as ASP.NET. If there is nothing ASP.NET specific to your question, you should remove that tag.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET, it would be helpful for us to see the code behind.

Comment: i have no code behind. just want to create 3 file uploads in one asp page.i dont want to use FileUpload control since i want to style the uploader.